# Unable to connect remotely with Redis based Nestjs microservice

Tags: docker, redis, microservices, nestjs

I have a Redis based dockerized microservice that I have deployed on a vps.
In main.ts, this is how the service is exposed:

```
const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(AppModule, {
    transport: Transport.REDIS,
    options: {
        url: "redis://redis:6379"
    }
});
await app.listen();
```

The redis is the service name within the docker-compose.yml

I have it deployed on vps and it runs fine and I can ping/telnet to the server

The client app is a regular dockerized NestJS app that tries to connect to the microservice in the following way:

```
 ClientsModule.registerAsync([{
    name: "PAIGHAM_SERVICE",
    imports: [ConfigModule],
    useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        transport: Transport.REDIS,
        options: {
            url: "redis://[IP-ADDRESS]:6379"
        }
    }),
    inject: [ConfigService]
}])
```

The `IP_ADDRESS` is the external IP assigned to the VPS hosting the microservice

But the client is unable to connect to the service.
I also health-checked but it times out:

```
return this.health.check([
    () => this.microservice.pingCheck<RedisOptions>("service", {
        transport: Transport.REDIS,
        options: {
            url: "redis://207.180.210.3:6379"
        }
    })
])
```

I have no clue what wrong I am doing.
Any immediate help would be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
This is doker-compose.yml for the microservice:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  service:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./docker/service/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - "${API_FOLDER_PATH}/src:/app/src"
    networks:
      - paigham-network
  db:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./docker/db/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: paigham
    ports:
      - 5432:5400
    networks:
      - paigham-network
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    command: [ "redis-server", "--bind", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "6379" ]
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    volumes:
      - cache:/data
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - paigham-network
  redis-commander:
    image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOSTS=local:redis:6379
    ports:
      - 8089:8081
    networks:
      - paigham-network
networks:
  paigham-network:
    external: false
volumes:
  db-data:
  cache:
    driver: local
```

Comment: Have you published the redis port on the remote host (i.e. by using the `ports` directive in your `docker-compose.yaml`)? Can you show us your compose file?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply @FullyBuzzwordCompliant
I have edited my post to include the docker-compose.yml